# Entity framework 4 updating the model when a table changes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4.

I have my model file with my tables on it.  If I go and add a new column to one of my tables (in SQL Server) how do I update the table in the model without having to go and delete and re-adding it to the model?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option when you right click anywhere in the model (*.edmx): `Update Model From Database...`
Then a wizard will look for any differences (Add / Refresh / Delete). So if you need to update a table, go to the Refresh tab and select your table.

Mind you, this is only possible in an Entity Framework model, not in a LinqToSql model.

Comment: @Roel: Thanks. I didn't see the refresh tab on update model from database option.

Comment: @Roel: I just did, it told me to wait a couple of minutes before I could accept it.

Comment: @Brendan Vogt: No problem, I just remembered that too. Thanks!

Comment: @Roel: I am still having this issue.  I added a new column and the model was updated.  I then changed this column name in the table to something else.  I then updated the model.  The new column is there, and the old one.  How do I remove the old one?

Comment: hmm maybe you have to manually remove the column from your model in that case... I'll have a look later and see if I can reproduce this.

Comment: I just undid my changes from TFS. And then I updated my model. I always used to delete the model from the design view, but then I lost a lot of other stuff as well.